# Close Bootstrap 4 tab pane

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to open / close a Bootstrap 4 tab pane after clicking on a tab link. Basically creating a toggle effect with each tab pane. The final product is a vertical sidebar nav where you can open / close each tab pane.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>


$(".nav-link.active").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anycircle/pen/dNMPrW

Comment: You're code looks like it right from the Bootstrap docs, and the jQuery doesn't really doesn't accomplish anything.

Comment: Are you trying to hide a tab after a header is clicked a second time?  Based off your jquery it looks like you want to remove the active class when a nav item is clicked while already active.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yea the HTML is directly from the doc because my markup is the exact same (plus some custom classes for styling purposes only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to hide the active `.tab-pane` data after the nav is clicked a second time you can update your jQuery to something like this:

```
$(".nav-link").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('#' + this.hash.substr(1).toLowerCase()).toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

And here is a codepen of that working:
http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/dNMyry

Comment: Thanks, this works except after you close a pane you should be able toggle the same pane back open.

Comment: @user3063628 Updated the answer and the codepen to use `.toggleClass()` which should solve your issue.

Comment: Still not working for me. I've created a pen to show my markup. http://codepen.io/anycircle/pen/dNMPrW

Comment: @user3063628 it was getting the text value of the nav like your question was using.  In the example from the codepen you just sent you are not using text, you are using an image so that method didn't work.  I updated the method to be based off the hash value of the href instead of text.  Should be more reliable in the long run anyway.  Check out the answer and the codepen for the updated `this.hash.substr(1)` code.

Comment: this works! thanks. Now that the pane has the active class removed how would I also remove the active class of the tab itself?

Comment: @user3063628 I'm not sure but if you'd like to open up another question you can send me the link and I can look into that when I have a chance.